# JSON.NET deserialize JSON to object with customized rules

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am trying to deserialize some JSON for which the format has changed.

Previously, the JSON format was like this:

```
{
  "crs": [123],
  "plugins":{...},
  // other fields...
}
```

So, I defined my class as the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("crs")]
    public List<int> { get; set; }

    // other fields
}
```

And I deserialized it like this:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var myclass = (MyClass) serializer.Deserialize(jsonInput, typeof(MyClass));
```

But now, the JSON format has changed.  The `crs` field has been removed from the root and put into `plugins` as in the following:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    {
      "crs": [
        {
          "number": 123,
          "url": "url/123"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't want any fields other than the `number` and I want to keep the original interface of `MyClass`, so that I don't need to modify other related methods which use it.

Which means that:

```
Console.writeline(myclass.crs) 
=> [123]
```

And I want to keep the way that I am currently deserializing.

```
var myclass = (MyClass) serializer.Deserialize(jsonInput, typeof(MyClass));
```

How do I make a modification to get this result? I was thinking I could customize the `get` method of `crs` to retrieve the `number` from the `plugins` field, but I am new to .NET so I need some help.  Here is my idea:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<int> crs { get {
       // customize the get method and only retrieve the crs number from plugin field
    }}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what your `json object` or `C# Model Class` looks like?
`// other fields` - knowing what goes here would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a couple of extra classes to aid in deserialization, you can use the approach you suggested.

Define a `Plugin` class and a `Crs` class like this:

```
public class Plugin
{
    public List<Crs> crs { get; set; }
}

public class Crs
{
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }  // you can omit this field if you don't need it
}
```

In your `MyClass` class, add a `plugins` property as a `List<Plugin>`, and then you can make your `crs` property pull the data from the `plugins` list to get the `List<int>` you want:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<Plugin> plugins { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<int> crs 
    { 
        get
        {
            return plugins.SelectMany(p => p.crs).Select(c => c.number).ToList();
        }
    }

    // other fields
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am new to .net ecosystem and this is really helpful!

Comment: No problem; glad I was able to help!